# How to PIVOT without hardcoding column names in SQL Server/Azure?

Tags: sql-server, pivot, azure-sql-database

Given the following simplified scenario.

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SourceData;
CREATE TABLE SourceData
(
    [Timestamp] DATE NOT NULL,
    [Point] NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    [Value] FLOAT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO SourceData
VALUES
('2020-01-01', 'A', 0.25),
('2020-01-01', 'B', 0.5),
('2020-01-01', 'C', 0.99),
('2020-01-02', 'A', 0.30),
('2020-01-02', 'B', 0.75),
('2020-01-02', 'C', 1.50),
('2020-01-03', 'A', 0.35),
('2020-01-03', 'B', 0.80),
('2020-01-03', 'C', 1.75)


SELECT 
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        [Timestamp],
        [Point],
        [Value]
    FROM SourceData
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    AVG([Value])
    FOR [Point] IN (A, B, C)
) AS PivotTable;
```

Returns:

```
Timestamp   A       B       C
2020-01-01  0.25    0.5    0.99
2020-01-02  0.3     0.75   1.5
2020-01-03  0.35    0.8    1.75
```

[Fiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c0293ff165c9059769040eb807b02bad)

Is it possible to obtain the same results without hardcoding the column names inside the `PIVOT` clause? I do not know in advance which are the unique values in the `Point` column.

Or... is there a way to specify them based on a query?

Comment: If you want to use PIVOT in SQL, the names are required.  The QP needs that to compile the plan.  You can build dynamic SQL if you want, but there's a point where you need to find the list when compiling the query.  In Access it is done as a final operator - basically a cursor, whereas in SQL it can be composed within the language wherever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using a dynamic pivot query.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.Point) 
            FROM SourceData c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Timestamp, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select Timestamp
                    , Value
                    , Point
                from SourceData
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(Value)
                for Point in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=483409ff1b24f137cf1ef881ddfd7d88) link.